# How to Convert Array of Objects to Array of Integers in Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this object result:

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]
```

How can I convert this to

```
[1,2,3]
```

in Lodash?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `lodash` for this, you can do this easy to achieve with a `map` function.

```js
var x = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]

var y = x.map(n => n.id);
console.log({y})
```